# Journey Builder Validation Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, validation, journeybuilder

My DOR is Service Cloud. I trigger my DOI Journey with a Salesforce Data Event and the field `Newsletter_Optin=TRUE`. The DOI link brings the subscriber to a profile center from where he can make his updates. From JB I update the contact to `Nl_Optin_confirmed=TRUE`.

In this DOI-link I need to have the Identifier which can be the Salesforce ID (`Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c`) which I think is transferred over Salesforce Data Event to Journey Builder.

I have an Email with this AMPScript. In the Journey Builder I get a Validation Error.

Anyone with an Idea on that?

```
%%[
  Var @rows, @row, @Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c
  Set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('lead', 'Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c', 'Email', Email)
  Set @row = ROW(@rows, 1)
  Set @id = Field(@row,'Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c')
]%%
```

DOI-Link

`www.domain.com/%%=@Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c=%%`

Comment: can you share the validation error ?

Answer (score 2):

That error would be related to your `Email` personalization string. When using Salesforce Data Sources, you need to define the relationship to the Attribute using the syntax ObjectName:FieldName.

For example, if you are using the Email field from the Salesforce Contact Object in your Salesforce Data Event, your AMPscript would look like this:

```js
%%[
  Var @rows, @row, @Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c, @email
  Set @email = AttributeValue('Contact:Email')
  Set @rows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('lead', 'Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c', 'Email', @email)
  Set @row = row(@rows, 1)
  Set @id =field(@row,'Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c')
]%%
```

Note that I have set the `@email` variable using AttributeValue(), which is best practice as if the attribute is not available in the context of the email, you won't get an error.

You can check available Attributes to use in your email from the Sales and Service Cloud Attribute Group in Contact Builder:

[image: attribute sets]

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide the error message I can only guess, but if you want to append the value of your Id-variable to the Domain, you need to use the AMPscript-function `V(1)`:

```
www.domain.com/%%=V(@Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c)=%%
```

However, if you want to make the link clickable you need to concatenate the URL-parts using `Concat(1,2)` and use the `RedirectTo(1)` function in the href-attribute of your link:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat('www.domain.com/', @Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c))=%%">www.domain.com/%%=V(@Salesforce_ID_18_Digits_Lead__c)=%%</a>
```

Documentation of the used AMPscript functions:

- [`V(1)`](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/v/#v)
- [`Concat(1,2)`](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/concat/)
- [`RedirectTo(1)`](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/redirectto/)

Using the email validation tool helps finding problems and normally provides slightly more detailed error messages than the validation within journey builder. More info can be found in the how to [Validate an Email](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/validate_an_email/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I wanted to test your examples but I still get this validation error, which cannot be issued by a missing physical mailing address or profile center link, because I turned this "feature" of with help by the support.

I opened a ticket and hopefully get an answer.

The error when testing my journey:

> Error occured during triggeredsend publish and activation. The email specified for the job did not pass validation.
>
> EmailId: '1232'
>
> EmailName: 'DOI_MULTILANGUAGE_LEAD_ID'
>
> Additional info: {
>
> errorMessage: Publish triggered send error. The triggered send could not be published because the attempt to create a new job failed. See inner exception for detail.
>
> TriggeredSendID: 0f1d4fe4-d733-e711-9ac1-1402ec653a5c
>
> Triggered Send Name: DOI_MULTILANGUAG - 307c265d8d574eca8e61f2584592508c
>
> ClientID: 7296517
>
> CustomerKey: 987
>
> }